# Why is my splash animation not working when I have an async call?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-animation, splash-screen

I have a splash animation which I start in onCreate and a call to read current location(Google Play Services) in onStart. But because of this my animation doesn't start at all.

Any idea why is this happening?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    setLogoAnimation();
}


 private void setLogoAnimation() {
    Animation blink =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.blink);
    imgLogo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);
    imgLogo.startAnimation(blink);
    imgLogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}


 protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                imgLogo.setAnimation(null);
            }
        }
    });

    t.start();


    readLocation();
}
```

When I comment out this call to readLocation(), it works perfectly.

```
public void readLocation() {
    // Check if Google Play Services are available on device
    prefs  = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    if (checkPlayServices())
    {
        // Build Google API Client
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        if (mGoogleApiClient !=null)
        {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

}
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, activity,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

 @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // Once connected with google api, get the location
    getLatLong();
    getAddressFromLocation(latitude, longitude,
            context, new GeocoderHandler());

}
```

Comment: What is `readLocation()` doing? Is it resource heavy? If so, is it blocking the UI thread?

Comment: Can you post your code in `readLocation()`? You should also be aware that `onStart()` is called every time your Activity returns from the background, not only after `onCreate(Bundle)`.

Comment: updated the code. Please check.

Comment: Why are you doing this on a sparated thread?

Comment: but you didnt call the `onStart() ` function in the code

Comment: @Ibukun that's the overridden method of Activity

Comment: oh, okay. thanks @Panda

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post can help , its explaining running threads on UI. 
http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2014/04/06/run-code-on-mainui-thread-on-android/
Accesing the UI thread from other thread can cause problems.